# What should we do with the questions tagged as "meta"

Tags: discussion, meta

There are 15 questions tagged as meta. What should we do with them?

Answer (score 3):

I will be running through them and either migrating them to meta.electronics.SE or deleting them (much less likely) if they no longer apply.

Comment: I worry that you don't have enough categories there.  As I read it, the questions have not two (meta and inapplicable) but four categories: (1) True meta questions about acceptable behavior on the site, (2) questions about the merger between CH, EE, and SE 2.0, (3) questions which aren't really meta, and should just have the tag stripped (or be deleted), and (4) historical questions about the formation of Chiphacker.